# Printf not printing correctly with returned string pointer

Tags: pointers, printf

I am at a complete loss here. I am trying to learn C and wrote a function that takes a string, copies it to an array while turning all uppercase letters into lowercase, and then returns a pointer to the string.

By all measures, the code works. If I use printf to print the string from inside the original function (the tolowercase function below), it prints correctly. If I loop through the returned array pointer and print each character individually, it works (look in the main method). I have checked that the null character is present in the returned array, and it is (again, in the main method).

But still, when I try to print the string from the main method, it's like it will only print up to a certain number of characters, and then, for the rest of the characters, it gives garbage characters that make no sense. They are not the characters I see when I loop through the pointer.

Here is the code. I have left in the code where you can see that I have looped through the returned pointer and got everything I should:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stringlen(char *p);
char *tolowercase(char *p);

int main() {
    char *p;
    p = tolowercase("HELLO THERE I AM REALLY CON");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", *(p+i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        printf("%c", *(p+i));
        if (*(p+i) == '\0')
            printf("good");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}

int stringlen(char *p) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*(p++) != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

char *tolowercase(char *p) {
    int len;
    char lower[(len = (stringlen(p) + 1))], *s;
    char *r;
    printf("%d\n", len);
    s = lower;
    r = lower;
    while (*p) {
        if ((*p < 'a') && (*p != ' ')) {
            *s = (*p) + 32;
        } else {
            *s = (*p);
        }
        printf("%c %c ", *p, *s);
        p++, s++;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", r);
    return r;
}
```

It is the last printf statement in the main method that gives me the gibberish. As mentioned, it seems to have to do with number of characters in the string. At one point, it did not seem to like anything over 15 characters. Now, it is about 26 characters.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to the start of your local array (pointer `r`, array `lower`). Once the function has returned, that array is *gone*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m not sure I’m following. The for loops you see in the main method are correctly printing. If the array is gone, how are they correctly printing? Also, the printf statement does print up to a certain number of characters. So if the array is gone, how is it printing anything at all? Sorry, I am quite new at this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: They're correctly printing *sometimes* (as you said, sometimes 25 chars, sometimes less). The pointer `p` is pointing into an area on the stack that is no longer part of any variable. As you call other functions, etc, they use that previously used space on the stack, overwriting it with data for their own use. Here's a link to get you started: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Keywords/return

Comment: Here's an SO answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope